# How to Integrate Wufoo form and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wufoo

I followed this tutorial [Integrating Google Analytics with Wufoo](http://borism.net/2008/12/24/integrating-google-analytics-and-wufoo/) but I can't get it to work, it says

> "All we need to do is include a small javascript file that will parse our google analytics >cookie and pass it to wufoo using url modification."

My question is where I will put the jquery script? I am no expert with javascript and jquery and I am seeking your help on how to implement this. The original author of this tutorial is no longer active and wufoo forum is offline at this moment.

TIA
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Once  you have created the .js file, name it whatever you want, lets say wufoo-ga.js and put it on your server in the folder that holds your web site. You probably have a folder somewhere called *js* or *scripts*. It would be best to put it there. In this example lets say you put the file in *mywebsitefolder/js*. You then need to put the following code into the html of the page you want to use:

```
<script src="js/wufoo-ga.js"></script>
```

This will call the script that you created and put in the *js* folder